# Braintree API: Canceling a subscription is not reflecting the subscription status change in PayPal Dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, braintree, paypal-subscriptions, braintree-rails

I have implemented a subscription plan for users, I have two plans on my site

- 4 weeks plan with initial amount of 1.95$ and 28 days trial
- Yearly Plan

I am using the Braintree API to create and cancel user subscription, here is subscription creation flow:

- Backend Creates the subscription for user on Braintree using the API and it is automatically reflected on the user's PayPal dashboard.

Create flow works perfectly fine, but when I cancel the subscription using the Braintree API, its not reflected on the user's PayPal dashboard.

Here is the cancel workflow:

- User click on `Cancel Subscription` button
- Backend sends cancel request to the Braintree using API
- Braintree dashboard shows subscription with inactive status but on PayPal dashboard it is still active